# I want to extract District_NameEng (dictionary value) from array in swift4.0

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift

My response is: 
`func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)` 
 here in "string"(array) hold all the values. and I want to get the value of "District_NameEng" how I get ??
 In this Picture my response which I get from service [json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maMIj.png)

Comment: post code , so others can get idea, what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `enumerated()` function of Swift array.

```
var arrayJSON : [[String:Any]] = [["Loc_District" : "8119", "districtname" : "AJAMER", "District_NameEng" : "AJMER"],["Loc_District" : "8104", "districtname" : "ALWAR", "District_NameEng" : "ALWAR"]]
```

Use this code to extract value for `District_NameEng` from array

```
for (index , dict) in arrayJSON.enumerated(){

    if let districtName = dict["District_NameEng"] as? String{
         print(districtName)
    }
}
```

To parse json from response in Swift 4, make use of `Codable` protocol.
Check this [link](https://troz.net/2017/06/json-parsing-in-swift-4/) for more information.

Comment: i did not want  extract my value like this     arrayJSON : [[String:Any]] = [["Loc_District" : "8119", "districtname" : "AJAMER", "District_NameEng" : "AJMER"],["Loc_District" : "8104", "districtname" : "ALWAR", "District_NameEng" : "ALWAR"]] .  because this value is come from a service and in form of array

Comment: func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) . here in "string"( array)  hold all the values

Comment: your solution is  work for me.but i did not able  to pass value  in form of dict. bcz i get a array reponse.then plz tell me how i get my all dic from this array and then i pass this dic for next

Comment: You are already getting `dict` in `arrayJSON.enumerated()`, you can make use of that `dict`.

Comment: @ technerd actually this dic. is made by you for 2 value... but i have got 38 value like this from service ,,, then may i write this manually as you write ?no any solution behalf of this?

Comment: Please post your code in question and mention where you are facing issue.

Comment: Please post code , no one can get from this question what you are looking for. Post your code , which you trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) 
    if let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let jsonArr = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
    for json in jsonArr {
            if let district_NameEng = json["District_NameEng"] as? String {
                   print(district_NameEng)

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If you please update your JSON string with 2 or 3 values(array content) then it will be better to solve this problem.

Comment: if "string" have all value and this string pass  for jsonserialization after show nil value then how and when i update it?

Comment: @singh please update the string value on this question. I actually want to know which type of string you have.

Comment: @ faysal i have already attached a image of my response(string) in my question

Comment: @singh I saw your attached image but it is not enough to execute any operation. If you please add the string with some values then it will be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: @ faysal i think you did not find my actual question! i just want to get value of "district_NameEng" from an array. and this array name is string....like in obj-c "value for key" method is used then what is used in swift? simply  i want to know how i get my alldictionary from an array

Comment: Simply by using this, you can get all dictionary from an array. But your question `foundCharacters string: String` here string is a String not an array. If this string contains arry and joined by `,` then first get the array from string and then get all dic value by using this 

`for dicValue in array {
            if let district_NameEng = dicValue["District_NameEng"] as? String {
                   print(district_NameEng)
            }
        }`

Comment: @ faysal thanks for this advise... now i understand what i do